# Not a loaded control class in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to open VB6 project and get this error in log file,

Line 190: Class SampleQueryControl.SampleCtrl of control SampleCtrl1 was not a loaded control class

Any idea why this error occurred?

Comment: Possibly because you have a custom control that has not been built yet.

Comment: I just checked out the project from repository and all the project contains ocx/dll. I think project should atleast open without compiling anything else.

Comment: if the project needs that reference to build something like a form, it is warning you that something is missing.  it isnt compiling its telling you it cant compile

Comment: User controls are ctl files not dll/ocx. And they are just a form with a funny extension - they are compiled at the same time as rest of the program.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have installed the components which were missing and I could open the project. Thanks.

Comment: I had a case of this, where the GUID for the control had changed. Used a text editor to update the GUID in the .vbp and .frm files. I dropped the control in a new project, to use the new project as a reference on how the old project should be updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vb6: error Class xxx of control xxx was not a loaded control class when try to use in another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049713/vb6-error-class-xxx-of-control-xxx-was-not-a-loaded-control-class-when-try-to-u)