# vb6: error Class xxx of control xxx was not a loaded control class when try to use in another project

Tags: user-controls, vb6

In a vb6 project, i created an usercontrol and I put in a form, when I try to use that form (with my control)  in another project,  the IDE give me the error: Class xxx of control xxx was not a loaded control class.

I researched in web but  i dont found a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you added your user control to the new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to compile the usercontrol and then reference the usercontrol from the second project.

Comment: The answer is: it is not possible use the user control (.ctl) in two different projects without have the error. The solution is what Clara says. But in my case, i dont want compile, at least for now, because is a control that going to have changes, and many clients are going to use it, and i dont want to register every time i compile. What i going to do ?: I going to live with the problem for a time till i be sure the control is complete, then compile the control. Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this but I think that once you've compiled the control at least once you can run two instances of the VB6 IDE in order to debug - that would probably also allow you to make changes

Comment: Correct! Just compiled the project and error gone